# How to post json file with pydruid?

Tags: python, druid, pydruid

I went through pydruid documentation [docs](https://github.com/druid-io/pydruid) and could not find a single example where I can use the existing JSON file to convert it into a format which pydruid can use to post(start the job). We are using older version of druid so we may not have all the latest functionalities. I'm sure I might be able to achieve the same behavior with `pycurl` but somehow feel pydruid is a better approach here. Can someone post an example of how I can use the exiting JSON file with prdruid?

Comment: Why not requests?

Comment: @cricket_007 because I feel pydruid is well suited for druid related jobs.

Comment: There are 2 ways using which you can append/update the data to an existing segment.

Reindexing and Delta Ingestion

Comment: @kapmirch thanks but I think that does not answer my question. I'm not looking for data ingestion ways. I'm looking to leverage `pydruid` package to use my existing JSON file for jobs.

Comment: Sure. But you're just using the regular api, which is http, so use an HTTP library

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 that was my initial instinct to use `pycurl` or `request` to hit druid api. I just wanted to see if there are any converters/wrappers that can go well with `pydruid` so that I can leverage more features that comes with this package.

Comment: There might be... Did you find any documentation or source code that does that?

Comment: It's already using requests, anyway https://github.com/druid-io/pydruid/blob/master/pydruid/db/api.py#L12